# TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable When trying to make a histogram in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

When I try and run the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import normal

masses = []

f = open( 'myfile.txt','r')
f.readline()
for line in f:
   if line != ' ':      
   line = line.strip()    # Strips end of line character 

   columns = line.split() # Splits into coloumn 
   mass = columns[8]      # Column which contains mass values
   mass = float(mass)
   masses.append(mass)
   mass = math.log10(mass)
   #print(mass)


#gaussian_numbers = #normal(size=1000)
plt.hist(mass, bins = 50, normed = True)
plt.title("Gaussian Histogram")
plt.xlabel("Value")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.show()
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Khary\My Documents\Python\HALOMASS_READER_PLOTTER.py",  line 23, in <module>
plt.hist(mass, bins = 50, normed = True)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2191, in hist
ret = ax.hist(x, bins, range, normed, weights, cumulative, bottom, histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 7606, in hist
if isinstance(x, np.ndarray) or not iterable(x[0]):
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Can one not use floats when doing histograms or am I missing something else? Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have one more question. How can I take the average of the quantities in the bin? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Based on [the docs](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist), I'm *pretty* sure `mass` doesn't belong there in the `hist()` call...

Comment: @Surfcast23, You should proivde hist() with the list of mass which is **masses**, not **mass**. Matplotlib tried to breakdown **mass** into elements but it failed as it is a singleton float, reason your geeting the "unscriptable" error.

Comment: It actually takes a two-dimensional structure, either a ragged sequence or a 2D NumPy array.

Answer (score 0):

@Ignacio diagnosed it right: you were providing the wrong variable to the hist() call. You had confused the singleton float variable **mass** for the list variable containing several floats **masses**. hist() requires a list or any iterable Python container. Your code can be improved by removing some of those things which are not needed and prevent confusion. As a general advice, it's dangerous to use a variable name when the pluralized/past-tensed forms are also used.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mass_list = []

with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = [line.strip().split() for line in f.readlines()]
    mass_list.extend([float(row[8]) for row in data if row[0] != ''])

plt.hist(mass_list, bins=50, normed=True)
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. How do a go about taking the logarithm of the values that I have using your method?

Comment: You mean, the log of each mass?  <br/>
`from math import log10`
`mass_list.extend([log10(float(row[8])) for row in data if row[0] != ''])`

Comment: @ Shimofuri yeah each mass. Also the data in my outfile is a column can I just change row to column in your script? Thanks again

Comment: @surfcast23, you can change _row_ to any other name... it would be meaningful however as _data_ contains rows and the columns are actually accessed by [index]. What I used there is called a "list comprehension".

Comment: oh I thought that when you used "row" or "column" either a "row" or "column" in the data set was read. thanks for the clarification. Also for the sake of learning a bit more about this how could I modify my existing script to do what yours does? Is it simply a matter of reassigning  variable names?